# Creating a nested dictionary with a for loop in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop, append

I am trying to get the Expected Output below where it makes subfolders named `John1, John2, John3` below and then it adds `{0: 'John', 1: 'John', 2: 'John', 3: 'John'}` values to each essentially creating a nested dictionary. How would I be able to do that and get the Expected Output?

```
dicts = {}
keys = range(4)
name_vals = ['John'+str(k+1) for k in range(3)]
values = ["Hi", "I", "am", "John"]
for k in name_vals:
    for i in keys:
        for x in values:
            dicts[k][i] = x
```

Expected Output:

```
{John1: {0: 'John', 1: 'John', 2: 'John', 3: 'John'},
 John2: {0: 'John', 1: 'John', 2: 'John', 3: 'John'},
 John3: {0: 'John', 1: 'John', 2: 'John', 3: 'John'}}
```

Comment: So you want all values of the inner dictionary to be John?

Comment: are you sure your expected output is correct? are you expecting this `{0: 'Hi', 1: 'I', 2: 'am', 3: 'John'}`?

Comment: What's the point of the `values` list if all the values are `John`?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
keys = range(4)
name_vals = ['John'+str(k+1) for k in range(3)]
values = ["Hi", "I", "am", "John"]
    
dicts = {}
for k in name_vals:
    subdict = {}
    for i in keys:
        subdict[i] = values[i]
    dicts[k] = subdict
            
dicts
```

output

```
{'John1': {0: 'Hi', 1: 'I', 2: 'am', 3: 'John'},
 'John2': {0: 'Hi', 1: 'I', 2: 'am', 3: 'John'},
 'John3': {0: 'Hi', 1: 'I', 2: 'am', 3: 'John'}}
```

if u want all values to be 'john' then just replace `values[i]` with `values[3]`

Answer (score 0):

this is the way with list comprehension

```
values = ["Hi", "I", "am", "John"]

{ f'Jhon{k+1}': {i: values[3] for i in range(len(values))} for k in range(3)}
```

Output:

```
{'Jhon1': {0: 'John', 1: 'John', 2: 'John', 3: 'John'},
 'Jhon2': {0: 'John', 1: 'John', 2: 'John', 3: 'John'},
 'Jhon3': {0: 'John', 1: 'John', 2: 'John', 3: 'John'}}
```